# OpenVSP Python API - Can't change wingspan

Tags: python, cad

I've written a Python program that loads a .vsp3 file and data from a CSV sheet, then updates the geometry in the .vsp3 and writes the updated geometry to a new file. Everything is working fine (even other parameters of the wing geometries) except changing wing spans of wing sections. For some reason the geometry does not update to the new span value.

I've tried different combinations of the three methods below:

```
mainWing_id = vsp.FindGeom("WingMain", 0)                  
vsp.SetParmVal(mainWing_id, "X_Rel_Location", "XForm", mainWing_x)               
vsp.SetParmVal(mainWing_id, "Y_Rel_Location", "XForm", mainWing_y)               
vsp.SetParmVal(mainWing_id, "Z_Rel_Location", "XForm", mainWing_z) 
vsp.SetParmVal(mainWing_id, "Span", "Plan", mainWingSpan) #attempt 1                     
vsp.SetParmVal(mainWing_id, "TotalSpan", "WingGeom", mainWingSpan) #attempt 2
vsp.SetParmVal(mainWing_id, "Span", "XSec_1", mainWingSpan/2.0) #attempt 3
```

I get no error messages. But the wing span does not change to the desired value. Same behavior for horizontal and vertical stabilizers. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue could lie with the driving parameters for the wing section. I'm also wrestling with the Python API and have been using the .vspscript examples as a guide.  In the Wing.vspscript example there is the following line:

```
//===== Change Driver =====//
SetDriverGroup( wid, 1, AREA_WSECT_DRIVER, ROOTC_WSECT_DRIVER, TIPC_WSECT_DRIVER );
```

I used this command but substituted span for area:

```
import openvsp as vsp

section = 1

wid = vsp.AddGeom("WING")
vsp.SetDriverGroup(wid, section, vsp.SPAN_WSECT_DRIVER, vsp.ROOTC_WSECT_DRIVER, vsp.TIPC_WSECT_DRIVER)
```

Here section is the index of the wing section you want to change. This way I can control the section planform using the span, root and tip chords.  This process is analogous to the GUI radio button selections in the Wing Section tab.  Hopefully this solves your problem!